# Implementing Objective-C Framework (TOCropViewController) method in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I am trying to implement a framework written in CocoaPods ([TOCropViewController](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast)) and have imported it in the bridging-header like this:

**Bridging Header**

```
#import <TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h>
#import <TOCropViewController/TOCropView.h>
#import <TOCropViewController/TOCropToolbar.h>
#import <TOCropViewController/TOCropOverlayView.h>
```

The problem I am facing is that I don't understand Objective-C and therefore I don't know how to implement this framework in Swift. This is the basic implementation documented on it's page:

```
- (void)presentCropViewController
{
UIImage *image = ...; //Load an image

TOCropViewController *cropViewController = [[TOCropViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
cropViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:cropViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)cropViewController:(TOCropViewController *)cropViewController didCropToImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)cropRect angle:(NSInteger)angle
{
// 'image' is the newly cropped version of the original image
}
```

I tried to do this in Swift like this:

```
 self.presentCropViewController{
    }
```

But as expected, it gives me an error saying that the value of `ViewController` has no member `presentCropViewController`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will help with the translation, try to understand the relationship between Swift and Objective-C so you can do this in the future.

```
func presentCropViewController() {
    let image = ...

    let cropViewController = TOCropViewController(image: image)
    cropViewController.delegate = self
    present(viewController: cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle angle: NSInteger) {

}
```

More info found here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: It worked :) , the link will definitely help me do this in the future thank you!